# android align element at bottom of the screen

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am using `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to align at parent bottom but for this particular case is not valid. Parent is a relative layout that has fixed size and bigger that screen height. Now I need to place a textview aligned at bottom of screen and not parent bottom. How to reach it? thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="600dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/blogLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webviewBlog"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" 
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Volver"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Volvertxt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Volver"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30px"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClickVolver" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because, you are giving height in `dp` units of the parent layout. Make it `match_parent`.

**EDIT**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webviewBlog"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="600dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" 
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Volver"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Volvertxt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Volver"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30px"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClickVolver" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: height is in dp because I need it for any other reasons. Assuming that must be in dp and more that screen height, how to reach it? thanks

Comment: Okay. Can you tell me, in which layout these both Relativelayouts are? The parent of these two RelativeLayouts should be a RelativeLayout since you need 2nd RelativeLayout to be on bottom (it will be relative to parent layout).

Comment: ok, resuming, I need webview larger than screen height, and for that, only way that I found is set main layout in dp. This is properly working but also has effect over "Volver" relative layout, that must be  aligned at bottom of screen.

Comment: Change height of webview to 600dp or the blogLayouts height to 600dp.

Comment: Not working. Your solution is totaly logical but although webview is set to 600dp, only works when is less than sceen size. For example for 100dp is properly resized but for 600dp is resized to parent, 480 for example

Comment: well, partialy solved, I set textview at top. Not desired layout but fully functional. Thank you to make me look inside.

Answer (score 1):

```
I have modified your code hope it solves your problem


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webviewBlog"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" 
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Volvertxt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Volver"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30px"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="onClickVolver" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: not solved :( webview still getting screen (parent) dimensions

Comment: are you not able to view your Text View @ botttom?

Comment: yes sure, textview is at bottom but webview is also set al screen height!

Comment: so what size do you want webview to be?