# How to put textview and tablelayout in scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I am working with android layout.I have two table in my layout and i have put those table in scrollview.But currently the problem that i faced is that the whole layout is not displayed in the small screen android phone.I want the layout in scrollview but as i have googled it for that,I have found that i can not put these much contents(textviews,table layout) vertical scrollview. Is there any other way for displaying all the contents in the small screen mobile phone? Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:background="@drawable/back1"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Name Label -->


    <!-- Input Name -->


    <!-- Input Name -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="264dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/maintable"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" >
        </TableLayout>




        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/maintable1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
        </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/list"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        style=" android:listViewStyle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

    </ListView>

     </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="horizontal"  >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="ff"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorLink="#FFFFFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="fv"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorLink="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have two `ScrollViews` on one screen. The scrolling could get very strange for your users. there is no cursor, so you can't just

To solve this, you can put everything into a scrollview like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="145dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:background="@drawable/back1"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"  >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    ...
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/maintable"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" >
        </TableLayout>
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/maintable1"
            android:layout_width="283dp"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
        </TableLayout>

    ...
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Or just put the two tables into a scrollview. If you do this, though, the contents of the tables may scroll off the screen and not be visible ever. You can use weighted layouts if you think the content will display well, but it probably won't. If you want to try, do it like this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="145dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"  >
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/maintable"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" >
        </TableLayout>
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/maintable1"
            android:layout_width="283dp"
            android:layout_height="500dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I have edited my code in the question.I want last two textview in the bottom of the screen and outside the scrollview..But this code is showing error:root element must be formated at the last linear layout structure

Comment: That has to do with aligning layouts with the bottom of the screen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035024/android-align-element-at-bottom-of-the-screen